# Checksum Algorithm that produces correct 16-bit checksum value for any given input

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, c

I need a checksum algorithm that produces the correct 16-bit checksum value for a given input. It's a packet recording from serial communication that I would like to reverse engineer.

I have two data files, one [dataset1.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18G3kbPePaDc2WByrOVqY3T_8JO5eV_h8/view?usp=sharing), that checksum is the last 2 bytes in the hex, for example, first entry:

4573500506000004047a6e126100eed1f268eb2de68d20a2f05b24842ef0e379976596733f20ee9143936adf5536f230c24b00005ee8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000093c1

Checksum (in hex): 93c1.

And the second dataset (where I suspect the same checksum algorithm is used) [dataset2.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zyGP1wbDHeVvg5mexLoOWHO38uIKC37A/view?usp=sharing). The checksum is known to be the fourth and fifth byte, for example, the first entry:

457304 ccba 0f8a231a

Checksum(in hex): ccba.

I am interested in the checksum algorithm for dataset1.txt (dataset2.txt is included, as it hopefully can provide some extra information).

If you think you have cracked it, drop me a message and I will provide a small testing dataset from which accuracy (in the case of ML methods, targeting 90%+ accuracy on unseen data) can be determined. In principle, any programming language can be used, but C-based syntax (C/C++/C#/Java) is preferred.

Comment: I don't think "please reverse-engineer this concrete value for me" or "identify the algorithm from this data dump" is a good fit here on Stack Exchange.  For some rationale, see https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100/351, https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/788/351, https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1097/351, https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888/351, https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/351.

Comment: Your approach sounds like "be a good dog and you'll get cookies" + implicit request for source code. Rude and off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

That checksum matches (perhaps accidentally, but it does match) an lsb-first CRC16 using 0xB31C as the reflected polynomial. That's if the checksum is actually 0xC193 but stored in little-endian, which wouldn't be strange. The polynomial was found by brute force.

I don't see how to match that with dataset2 though. This match could be a total fluke. I could not find any reference to that polynomial, neither in its reflected form nor in its "unreflected" form. There are certainly also other ways to get that checksum from that data. However, the fact that a CRC16 solution exists is not meaningless, because it is not the case that any combination of data and a crc has a solution for a polynomial that produces that crc from that data. The certainty that the match is meaningful is not very high, but it is not zero.

Example C# code to compute this type of crc, not accelerated using a lookup table or anything fancy, just a basic implementation:

```
static ushort crc16(byte[] data)
{
    int crc = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if ((crc & 1) != 0)
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xB31C;
            else
                crc = crc >> 1;
        }
    }

    return (ushort)crc;
}
```